# How do I make Charles Proxy sniff communication with VirtualBox (Vagrant)?

Tags: vagrant, charles-proxy

I am debugging a iOS app running on a simulator connecting to a server with a REST based API running on my local machine in a Virtual Machine (setup on Mac OS X using Vagrant and Virtual Box). However Charles won't pick up any of the traffic. As far as I can tell the communication happen by sending a packet out on my network card which gets routed back to my computer. At least if I pulled out the network cable the connection would be broken.

I have been able to see the traffic using Wireshark however, but I am not very familiar with that tool so I'd prefer to use Charles Proxy. Especially since I need to view HTTPS traffic which is easy to do in Charles.

Comment: How you set the network and port forwarding, could you show the content in `Vagrantfile`. My first feeling is, maybe you need set a private IP address for that vagrant instance, (for example, 192.168.1.1), then you can target that IP and its port with Charles, no need mix with your own IP (127.0.0.1).

Comment: One of these annoying issues were I got it working but I don't know why. Possibly my computer had gotten into a funny state that got solved with a reboot.